# append forloop iterator variable value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Am calling for loop and trying to append the $i value along with a variable called inside the function. not sure how to do this. Everytime I get a error saying "Unexpected token 'i' in expression or statement." any suggestions/idea please.

Thanks to Chris. His code works perfectly..

code :

```
function Get-Data {
    param(
        # Consider giving this a more meaningful name
        [Int]$i
    )

    # Assigns the value in the first index from -split to $null
    # and the value in the second index to $msgs.
    $null, $msgs = (b2b.exe -readparams "msgs${i}data" | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1) -split '='
    $null, $bytes = (b2b.exe -readparams "bytes${i}data" | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1) -split '='

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        MData = $msgs.Trim()
        BData = $bytes.Trim()
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i-le 3; $i++) {
    $data = Get-Data $i
    write-host "for MData$i $($data.MData)"
    write-host "for BData$i $($data.BData)"
}
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the variables when you use `$M$i`? Concatenation as a string? If so, you need to make it a string `"$M$i"`. If you are trying to create a variable based on $i you need to use `New-Variable "M$i"`.

Comment: You might be better served by adding an example of what you're attempting to parse with the recursive function. I've no problem passing $i around to control depth, but your variable assignment is confusing without context.

Comment: @Chris, am trying to create a variable based in $i, so guess, I need to try out your suggestion ie, New-Variable "M$i"..let me try now

Comment: I think you need to step back from this method for a minute, perhaps it's the wrong path. Adding a lot of `New-Variable` / `Get-Variable` is going to make it even more messy and confusing. Is there a reason you need to assign like that? Output can be returned via the output pipeline immediately without assignment, working-values can be passed into `Get-Data` to aid recursion.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Chris. your code does what I was trying to achieve. Many Thanks.. I have updated my original post so, it may be help for someone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you if this will work, but I would not rely on globally assigned variables to pass information out of a function.

I suspect it may need a bit of work around construction of the parameters for b2b.exe.

```
function Get-Data {
    param(
        # Consider giving this a more meaningful name
        [Int]$i
    )

    # Assigns the value in the first index from -split to $null
    # and the value in the second index to $msgs.
    $null, $msgs = (b2b.exe -readparams "msgs${i}data" | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1) -split '='
    $null, $bytes = (b2b.exe -readparams "bytes${i}data" | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1) -split '='

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        MData = $msgs.Trim()
        BData = $bytes.Trim()
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i-le 3; $i++) {
    $data = Get-Data $i
    write-host "for MData$i $($data.MData)"
    write-host "for BData$i $($data.BData)"
}
```